# Le difference entre « les » et « des » pour les phrases plus et moins spécifiques

Tags: grammaire, articles

J'ai lu beaucoup d'articles sur le sujet, mais c'est encore difficile pour moi. « Les » semble être spécifique et pas spécifique à la fois.

Par exemple, la phrase « Je n'aime pas les légumes. » je penserais qu'elle  est spécifique. « I don't like the vegetables (referring to a specific plate of vegetables) » en anglais, mais en fait, c'est général. « I don't like vegetables. »

Et ensuite, il y a la phrase « Les femmes de la région portent des robes noires. ».  Dans cette phrase, à la fois « les » et « des » sont généraux, et on ne pourrait pas dit « Les femmes de la région portent LES robes noires. » Parce que cela ferait référence à des robes spécifiques, non ? (« the local women wear the black dresses. » (referring to certain black dresses)). « Les femmes » est général, mais « des robes » est aussi général.

Enfin, pour la phrase « Cette chemise ? Le magasin ne les vend pas. », que penser ? C'est spécifique, non ? « The stores don't sell that (specific) shirt. » doit être la traduction. Si on veut dire que le magasin ne vend pas des chemises (les chemises? ) en général, alors on dirait « Le magasin n'en vend pas. » C'est correct ?

Donc comme vous pouvez le voir, je suis complètement perdu parce qu'il semble que « les » peut être général et spécifique en même temps. Mais « des » est seulement utilisé pour quelque chose non spécifique. Est-ce-que vous pouvez m'aider ? Y a-t-il une règle que je peux apprendre pour savoir quand utiliser « les » et « des » ?

Comment: Dans « Les femmes de la région portent des robes noires » le « Les » est bien spécifique, spécifié par « de la région ». D'ailleurs on pourrait dire « Toutes les femmes de la région... »

Answer (score 3):

1/ Non, « les » n'est pas spécifique mais générique dans « Je n'aime pas les légumes. », à moins qu'il existe un contexte où plusieurs chose sont à différencier ;

- Je n'ai pas aimé les légumes mais la viande était bonne. (*les légumes et la viande que l'on vient de nous servir*, déterminatif ou en d'autres mots « spécifique »)

2/ Ne pas vous tromper entre « des » équivalent à « de les » et « des », l'article partitif. Il s'agit de l'article partitif ; pour voir cela vous pourriez essayer un remplacement par un verbe similaire prenant « de » et voir si le sens est préservé ;

- Les femmes étaient vêtues de longues robes noires.

Cela est correct, donc il s'agit du partitif.

Les partitifs ne sont pas des articles qui puissent marquer la détermination ;

- L'aspect des  robes noires est lugubre.

Dans cet exemple il s'agit bien de l'article défini déterminatif « les » (de les).

Donc dans le cas général on ne peut pas, mais on peut construire un contexte où « Les femmes locales portent les robes noires. » est exactement ce qui convient, et « les » sera alors déterminatif.

3/ On dira plutôt « Ils ne vendent pas cette sorte/type de chemise dans ce magasin. ».
«  <s>Le magasin n'en vendent pas.</s>» est incorrect ; il faut dire « Ce magasin n'en *vend* pas. », mais ils est mieux de dire « Il n'y en a pas dans ce magasin. » ou « Ils n'en vendent pas dans ce magasin. »
Si on veut dire qu'aucune sorte de chemise n'est vendue dans le magasin on peut dire ceci ;

- Ils ne vendent pas de chemise dans ce magasin.

4/ Une bonne chose à faire, c'est l'examen de beaucoup d'exemples tirés de tous les textes possibles en essayant de déterminer s'il s'agit de « des » (une partie) ou de « des » mis pour « de les » spécifiant quelque chose *dans* le contexte qui n'est pas le tout d'une catégorie. Voilà un lien qui contient beaucoup d'information : [lien](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/003.html). Voyez aussi ce qui se trouve [là-dedans](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/051.html), c'est très instructif et bien expliqué.

P.S. tous les ex. sont de user **LPH**

Answer (score 2):

Pour ma part,  on utilise *les* lorsque je suis dans une situation où la phrase est préconstruite c'est à dire l'information est partagée ex : « ce sont les femmes d'hier. » Ici cette phrase veut simplement dire que ces femmes sont connues par les interlocuteurs.  Mais si je dis : « il y a des filles dans cette salle. » Ça veut dire que cette information n'est pas partagée par tous les interlocuteurs.

Comment: Vos explications ne correspondent pas à celles des grammaires françaises et je crois qu'elles ne sont pas des explications alternatives, ou en d'autres mots qu'elles ne sont pas une autre façon de comprendre la chose. Il n'est pas question d'une information partagée ou non au préalable dans le cas de « les » ; on peut savoir ce qu'étaient les femmes d'hier ou on peut l'ignorer complètement ; si vous voulez dire que l'ensemble reconnu est considéré en entier, c'est autre chose  mais il ne s'agit plus de partage de l'information ; « parties  d'un ensemble » irait. Cela ne semble pas utile.

Comment: Donne moi donc ton explication.  Car je sais la mienne est très vérifiée.  Si vous faites la linguistique vous en saurai d'avantage sinon cherchez un linguiste et demandez lui ce que c'est qu'une action preconstruite et construite

Comment: http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/045c2b.html voir n° 67 et n° 69

Comment: Mon explication, qui n'est pas la mienne en réalité mais celles de toutes les grammaires (il y a des variantes dans les termes choisi) et qui est la même pour l'anglais (plus ou moins) est celle dans ma réponse ci-dessus : il existe 2 possibilités, l'une étant celle de l'emploi générique (toute une sorte) et l'autre l'emploi déterminatif (spécifique), c'est à dire pour référer à un  sous ensemble que l'on connait.  1/ générique : « Les enfants ne parlent pas. » (tous les enfants) ; 2/ déterminatif : « Les enfants qui ont eu une bonne note sont heureux. » (seulement une partie).

Comment: Bien.  Mais j'aimerais aussi si vous le pouvez de faire des recherches sur mon explication.  Merci

Comment: Je ne trouve rien sur ces concepts de fait construits et faits préconstruits. Citez vos ouvrages et si je peux y avoir accès j'essayerai de chercher à comprendre.

Comment: Je suis étudiant au département d'anglais où j'étudie la linguistique. Ce sujet a été l'objet d'un cour où il fallait faire la différence entre le choix de l'usage de 'a (un) ' et 'the (le ou la)'. prenons une discussion de deux interlocuteur représentés par A et B. Si A dit ceci "j'ai vu une fille belle" cela suppose que c'est lui seul qui connaît cette fille et que B ne partage pas cette information. Et si il dit "J'ai vu la fille jolie d'hier " c'est que forcément les deux connaissent la meme information.  Or 'un ou une' font leur pluriel avec 'des' et 'le ou la' avec 'les'

Comment: dans l'exemple un si A dit "j'ai vu la belle fille ", cela change automatiquement le sense de la phrase et signifiera maintenant que A et B la connaisse et à ce moment B peut demander "laquelle ? " car à cause de 'la' qu'a utilisé A il sait qu'il la connaît lui aussi.  Mais s'il utilise 'une' B saura qu'il ne l'a connais pas . S'il y a encore des zones d'ombre posez moi des questions

Comment: C'est exact pour « une », mais ça c'est l'article indéfini. Dans le cas de l'article défini, ce n'est plus vrai ; dans « Il aime les belles filles. » l'information « les belles filles » peut être commune au deux interlocuteurs ou non ; si celui qui écoute n'a pas trop de maturité il se pourrait qu'il ne sache pas bien de qui il s'agit. Donc ce schéma d'explication n'est pas une base de raisonnement. De plus, la plupart du temps il existe un savoir commun, et donc pas de différence sur ce plan de l'information communiquée.  (champ 1/2)

Comment: Dans le cas du spécifique il est question d'une information commune préalable dans le contexte; c'est en raison de cet état de chose que la portée de l'article est automatiquement changée de générique à spécifique. ex. « Le livre est la meilleure source d'information. » (générique, tous les livres) _ Il a acheté un livre hier et d'autres choses. Le livre lui plait. » (spécifique, un seul livre, celui qui a été acheté hier. (champ 2/3)

Comment: Il semble donc que le raisonnement soit basé sur la reconnaissance soit d'un ensemble universel (générique) soit sur une information préalable commune aux locuteurs, l'existence de cette dernière excluant automatiquement la possibilité de la première et inversement pour sa non existence. Cependant pour le générique le concept d'information en rapport avec les locuteurs n'a pas d'incidence. (champ 3/3)

Comment: Bien je vous comprend parfaitement mais restons dans la logique de 'les' et 'des'.dans l'exemple  "Les livres lui plaît ", 'les livres ' est un cas général que chacun sait.  Mais si vous dites 'des livres lui plaît ' alors le sens de la phrase Change et l'on ne vous comprend plus bien car de quels livres s'agit il ? Ce qui veut dire que l'information est connue par une seule personne. Donc si vous hésitez entre l'utilisation de "les" et "des" dans cette phrase, voyez le contexte. Si vous exprimer une idée dont vous seul saviez,  utilisez "des" sinon "les" si l'idée est générale,  partagée

Answer (score 1):

Pour ma part je vois plutôt que DES est spécifique alors que LES est général.

- ex : une fille dans ce quartier est gentille.

Dans cette phrase je vois que Fille en question ici est connue.

- ex2 : La fille est belle.

Ici Fille en question reste générale. UN est le singulier de DES et LA est le singulier de LES.

Comment: L'article indéfini est plus spécifique que l'article défini ?  Est-ce que tu peux clarifier s'il te plaît et pour le pluriel ?  Voici le [tour] du site et le [FAQ] pour faciliter la révision, et bienvenue sur French Stack Exchange.